# how use these Material Design UI in my android studio while developing the application? ie .sketch file

Tags: android, sketchapp

Please help me out how to use the UI that designed by sketch in my android application either in eclipse or Android studio.

The sketch file in .sketch format

Comment: How to import UI assets or layouts from Sketch 3 directly to Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

You cant use it like that.
Sketch is just a prototyping app, it helps you get your Design right before you start coding to achieve that design.

Comment: How developed or reproduce  the UI that developed by Sketch3 tool in my app using android studio.

Comment: I'm sorry i can't understand your question, If your question is, how can you make the similar UI you made in Sketch3 tool in Android Studio? you have to code it in XML.

Comment: I don't  want develop the UI , But I want to use the UI which is in .sketch format

Answer (score 0):

I think could give it a look to the new **[UI Designer & Constraint Layout](https://youtu.be/csaXml4xtN8?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8jQTUYvIfqA9lMvSGQWtte&t=1558)** in Android Studio 2.2 Preview, It may help to create your layout quickly and easily, just using drag and drop.

More info:

- **[Google I/O 2016 talk about UI Designer & Constraint Layout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO9aX87hq9c)**
- **[Android Blog Post about UI Designer & Constraint Layout](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2016-05-20T07:15:00-07:00&max-results=7)**

Happy Coding!